Visual Studio: Auto Complete Template Braces < >
I can't find solution to auto complete angle braces <>.
I work in C++ and all others () {} work just fine. I browsed net and stack, but I could not figure this out.
Side note: I have vim plugin, but I don't think it matters.
"Example code to met posting criteria"
template<typename T>
void myFunction(T x) {};



There's a way to do it in Visual Studio Code.  But for Visual Studio, I don't think it supports completion for that out-of-the-box.  You probably could modify the open source Brace Completion extension for Visual Studio to support angle brackets for completion.

I think this is non-trivial for C++, as it is difficult for the editor to distinguish between  "less-than" and the beginning of a template argument list.

oh @molbdnilo , that make sense

As above comments said, visual studio does not support completion for templates <>. This issue is similar to this one 

Autocomplete gets confused by templates. Keep in mind that when a compiler is compiling temnplated code, it knows what the template parameters are going to be. In contrast, when you're writing code in a templated class, the autocomplete system doesn't know what the parameter is going to be.

As a workaround, if you consider using third-party extensions, you can install Resharper C++ and use ReSharper IntelliSense instead of Visual Studio.
By the way, you can also raise a feature request at Developer Community
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
